# Can I hook into the debug button in visual studio to add custom build functionality?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I started learning Electron today and I want to be able to run my project out of Visual Studio. I have gotten to the point where I want to be able to click debug and have Visual Studio launch the application. I used a msbuild task to run the electron.exe on the app directory of the project but this happens when I build. I would really want to be able to be able to click the debug button to launch the application. Does anyone know how I can change the behaviour of the debug button in Visual Studio 2015? I would like the debug button to call electron.exe with my app directory as its input so exactly what my custom task for msbuild is doing.

Here is the code for my msbuild task.

```csharp
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Build.Framework;
using Microsoft.Build.Utilities;

namespace Electron.Tasks
{
    public class ElectronBuild : Task
    {
        [Required]
        public string ElectronPath { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string AppPath { get; set; }

        public override bool Execute()
        {
            var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(Path.Combine(ElectronPath, "Electron.exe"))
            {
                Arguments = AppPath,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                UseShellExecute = false
            };

            var process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);

            var output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            output = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

            Log.LogMessage(output);

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the [Debug page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2wcdezs5.aspx) of the Project Designer (project properties) you can use the **Start external program** option to run electron.exe.